# Convert Runnable to Supplier

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

How can a `Runnable` be converted to a `Supplier`?

```
public <T> T useSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    // Does something with supplier and returns supplied value
    ...
    return value;
}

public void useRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
    // Somehow convert runnable to Supplier
    ...
    useSupplier(supplier);
}
```

Here I would like to reuse the method `useSupplier` for `useRunnable`, for example because I do not want to duplicate the code. The behavior of `useSupplier` does not matter for this question, let's say it wraps thrown exceptions, or uses the supplier in a synchronized block.

---

Edit: To clarify, the method `useSupplier` does not interact with the supplied value, it just returns it. The functionality of `useSupplier` is to retrieve the value from the supplier in some context, in my case it catches (specific) `RuntimeException`s, creates a new exception with it as cause and throws it:

```
public <T> T useSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    try {
        return supplier.get();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException runtimeException) {
        throw new MyException("Supplier threw exception", runtimeException);
    }
}
```

---

The following solutions do **not** work (in Java 8):

```
useSupplier(runnable);
useSupplier(runnable::run);
useSupplier((Supplier<Void>) runnable::run);
```

One solution I could come up with is creating a new `Supplier` which returns an arbitrary value:

```
useSupplier(() -> {
    runnable.run();
    return null;
});
```

Is there a smaller solution?

Edit: As pointed out by Holger in the comments, using `runnable::run` will also create new lambda instances since it is stateful, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23991339).

Comment: `run` method returns void, so you can't supply any value.

Comment: For `useRunnable` I do not care about the returned value. As I wrote, `useSupplier` uses for example the supplier in a synchronized block and this is what I want to have for `useRunnable` as well.

Comment: Consider using `Callable` which returns a value, instead of `Runnable`.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the semantics of `useRunnable(...)` and `useSupplier(...)`? From the naming, it transports that `useRunnable(...)` spawns a new threadt (at least for me).

Comment: @Turing85 I am catching (specific) `RuntimeException`s and throwing new exceptions with them as cause. So I do not care about what value the supplier returned, I only return it as well.

Comment: `() -> { runnable.run(); return null; }` does not create more objects than `runnable::run` would.

Comment: @Holger, since the lambda is capturing (captures the runnable) it likely cannot be reused, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466374

Comment: So does `runnable::run`. No difference.

Comment: Right, nevermind, I will update the question accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case you cannot avoid creating new object. Even if there is a method somewhere that converts a Runnable to a Supplier, it will create an object there.
So your solution is valid, you won't find any better.

Pay attention  to that Supplier is expected to provide values and Runnable just represents an action. They are used for different purposes. So your need of converting Runnable to Supplier may be a result of a design problem involved.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your design, you might just be looking for `Consumer` which accepts a type and just processes(consumes) it without return  a value and can be used to adapt a runnable as well, instead of a `Supplier` which on the other hand is expected to return (supplies) a value post-processing.

You could use something like :

```
private static <T> void useConsumer(Consumer<T> consumer, T val) {
    // Does something with supplier and returns supplied value
    consumer.accept(val);
}

public static <T> void useRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
    useConsumer(Runnable::run, runnable);
}
```

If the requirement is to use the `Supplier` for sure, then you can invoke that method as :

```
public static void useRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
    useSupplier(() -> runnable); // the useSupplier returns the 'runnable' when this method is called
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, now when you invoke `useRunnable`, the `useSupplier` would return the same `runnable`, but the method `useRunnable` is `void` again and hence its ignored altogether.

Comment: I want to have a method with `Supplier` as argument. I edited my question now to hopefully make it clearer that I do not want to process the supplied value.

Comment: No, the runnable should run. This way (with the edit I made to my question) the supplier would supply the runnable which would just be discarded.

Comment: @Marcono1234 *the supplier would supply the runnable which would just be discarded*, then why use `Supplier` even? that's why I initially suggested using `Consumer` instead. Do note, your implementation `() -> { runnable.run(); return null; }` does *`return`* something, be it `null`, but then it does not have anything to do it with `runnable`. Or does it?

Comment: See my edit to the question. When I use a supplier I am interested in the value but want all exceptions to be handled in a certain way. When I use a runnable I also want all exceptions to be handled in a certain way.

Comment: @Marcono1234  Then I doubt there is nothing better than `() -> {
    runnable.run();
    return null;
}` to call it with. When you just don't care of the `return` type of `useSupplier` and are primarily interested to deal with exceptions from `runnable` executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself using this pattern a lot in your codebase, it might be worth creating a `RunnableSupplier` class:

```java
public class RunnableSupplier<T> implements Supplier<T> {
    private final Runnable runnable;

    public RunnableSupplier(Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        runnable.run();
        return null;
    }
}
```

```java
public void useRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
    useSupplier(new RunnableSupplier(runnable));
}
```

I've made this class generic since `null` can be returned for suppliers of all generic types.  This makes it possible to use in library methods that require `Supplier`s of a specific type, so long as they allow null results.  If you want to enforce that it's always a `Supplier<Void>`, it's straightforward to make it non-generic and implement `Supplier<Void>` instead of `Supplier<T>`.